# Get term id of current taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: function, wordpress, metadata, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to create a function which adds additional custom data fields to my taxonomy pages, I have found [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/) plugin which add this capability.
Now I can get the saving the custom data works fine.. however trying to get the metadata on edit form pages is another story..

I've followed the documentation which says to use the following line..

```
get_term_meta($term_id, $key, $single)
```

However I am unable to get this to work.. I have to manually enter the term_id like so..

```
$term_meta = get_term_meta('36', '', true);
```

.. in order for it to work. 
Can someone tell me what code I would need for php get the term_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem

I had to use `$term_id->term_id` instead of just `$term_id` like this:

```
get_term_meta($term_id->term_id, $key, $single)
```

Comment: It's recommended that you add the full answer for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to do the debug

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

print_r ($term);
```

Thanks

Comment: Tried it, didnt have no luck. It doesnt return anything.

Answer (score 2):

yes true.

```
$idObj = get_category_by_slug(post_type);  
$id1 = $idObj->term_id;
```

If you are using any WordPress inbuilt function, then you need write the `objname->subkey`.